# React JS (Apollo): Searchbar filters every column except clerk names from table

Tags: reactjs, graphql

**Index.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { getIssuesPaginationQuery } from '@modules/CaseManager/CaseManagerDashboard/graphql';
import { Checkbox, Col, Icon, Row, Table } from 'antd';
import { removeFieldsFromObject } from '@components/helpers';
import FormattedDate from '@components/FormattedDate';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PermissionContext } from '@context/PermissionContext';
import { getCaseLink } from '@modules/CaseManager/CaseManagerDashboard/helpers';
import SearchInput from '@components/SearchInput';
import {
  MY_CASES_FILTER_KEY,
  SEARCH_FILTER_KEY,
  UNASSIGNED_FILTER_KEY,
} from '@modules/CaseManager/CaseManagerDashboard/constants';
import LocalizedText from '@components/i18n/LocalizedText';

const { Column } = Table;

function CaseManagerDashboard({ match: { params: { snr } = {} } = {} }) {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(20);
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState({});
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(
    snr || localStorage.getItem(SEARCH_FILTER_KEY) || ''
  );
  const [myCasesFilter, setMyCasesFilter] = useState(
    eval(localStorage.getItem(MY_CASES_FILTER_KEY))
  );
  const [unassignedCasesFilter, setUnassignedCasesFilter] = useState(
    eval(localStorage.getItem(UNASSIGNED_FILTER_KEY))
  );
  const { hasAccess } = useContext(PermissionContext);

  const { data, loading } = useQuery(getIssuesPaginationQuery, {
    variables: {
      options: {
        offset: (currentPage - 1) * pageSize || 0,
        limit: pageSize || 20,
        searchValue,
        sortBy: sorting && sorting.field,
        sortOrder: sorting && sorting.order === 'ascend' ? 1 : -1,
        myCases: myCasesFilter,
        unassignedCases: unassignedCasesFilter,
      },
    },
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
  });
  const {
    pagination: { items = [], totalCount = 0 } = {},
  } = removeFieldsFromObject(data);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Row>
        <Col span={7}>
          <h2>
            <LocalizedText textKey="search.input.searchaccident" />
          </h2>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row>
        <Col span={6}>
          <SearchInput
            onChange={(value) => {
              localStorage.setItem(SEARCH_FILTER_KEY, value);
              setSearchValue(value);
            }}
            initialValue={searchValue}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>

  <Row style={{ margin: '10px 0' }}>
        <Col span={24}>
          <Checkbox
            checked={myCasesFilter}
            onChange={(e) => {
              localStorage.setItem(MY_CASES_FILTER_KEY, e.target.checked);
              setMyCasesFilter(e.target.checked);
            }}
          >
            {' '}
            <LocalizedText textKey="search.checkbox.mycases" />
          </Checkbox>
(...)
```

**graphql.js**

```
port { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const getIssuesPaginationQuery = gql`
  query CaseManagerDashboard($options: CasePaginationArgsInput!) {
    pagination: getIssuesPagination(options: $options) {
      items {
        _id
        CaseNumber
        CaseNumberNormalized
        CreationDate
        UpdateDate
        AccidentDate
        SinglePerson {
          _id
          Firstname
          Lastname
          Birthday
          InvoiceCheck {
            CreationDate
          }
        }
        Clerks {
          _id
          Firstname
          Lastname
        }
      }
      totalCount
    }
  }
`;
```

**constant.js**

```
export const SEARCH_FILTER_KEY = 'CaseManagerDashboard.searchValue';
export const MY_CASES_FILTER_KEY = 'CaseManagerDashboard.myCases';
export const UNASSIGNED_FILTER_KEY = 'CaseManagerDashboard.unassignedCases';
```

**PaginationArgs.ts**

```
import { ArgsType, Field, InputType } from 'type-graphql'

@ArgsType()
@InputType('PaginationArgsInput')
export class PaginationArgs {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  offset?: number

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  limit?: number

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  searchValue?: string

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  sortBy?: string

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  sortOrder?: number
}
```

**CaseArgs.ts**

```
@ArgsType()
@InputType('AssignToClerkInput')
export class AssignToClerkArgs {
  @Field()
  snr: string = ''

  @Field(() => CopyAndAddCaseClerkInput)
  clerk: CopyAndAddCaseClerkInput = new CopyAndAddCaseClerkInput()
}

@ArgsType()
@InputType('CasePaginationArgsInput')
export class CasePaginationArgs extends PaginationArgs{
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  myCases?: boolean

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  unassignedCases?: boolean
}
```

**schema.graphql**

```
(...)

input CasePaginationArgsInput {
  limit: Float
  myCases: Boolean
  offset: Float
  searchValue: String
  sortBy: String
  sortOrder: Float
  unassignedCases: Boolean
}
(...)
```

I have a searchbar inside my **index.js**, which fetches results from the const **getIssuesPaginationQuery**.
The query contains option arguments for a case and pagination (**Pagination/CaseArgs.ts**) with an appropriate schema (like **searchValue**). I address the wanted property through keys written in a constant.js that leads to the the query named CaseManagerDashboard, in order to allow input options as explained above (input arguments).

**searchValue** uses the user's input (as String) in order to search within fetched data.
Patient full name works (first name & last name), same as case number, also checkboxes to filter specific data.

But when I enter a Clerk's name, I get no result, altough I received everything neccessary.
I'll attach a Screenshot of the network tab too.

Thanks in advance
[image: networktab]

Comment: BE problem? get it working in graphiql first

Comment: What do you mean? It does work. I mean I got the clerk names in a nested array, as you can see.

Comment: ... it doesn't mean it can be sorted by this field ... it's not a client side or graphql alone feature ... it must be supported by BE/resolvers